# SheetJS, Repaired Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

Tags: javascript, excel, ecmascript-6, spreadsheet, sheetjs

I use [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to export data to excel and looks like excel itself repair data. Data download good, but is it ok to receive this warning?
I've got and file.xlsx from UI, and when I open it via excel I received some warning was produced by Excel itself. 
[image: screenshot_5]
[image: screenshot_4]

**Code:**

```
const download = (url, name) => {
    let a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = url
    a.download = name
    a.click()

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}

function Workbook() {
    if (!(this instanceof Workbook))
        return new Workbook()

    this.SheetNames = []

    this.Sheets = {}
}

function s2ab(s) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length)

    const view = new Uint8Array(buf)

    for (let i=0; i !== s.length; ++i)
        view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF

    return view
}

export default data => {
    import('xlsx').then(XLSX => {
        const wb = new Workbook()
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data)

        wb.SheetNames.push('s')
        wb.Sheets[''] = ws

        const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'})

        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {type:'application/octet-stream'}))

        download(url, 'import.xlsx')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Sheet name length should not be more than 31. Microsoft Excel gives error if Sheet Name's length is more than 31.

Answer (score 2):

I it was obvious issue, to fix this, I set:

```
 const wbSheetNames = 'Custom Name'
        wb.SheetNames.push(wbSheetNames)
        wb.Sheets[wbSheetNames] = ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel will report the same error if you use invalid characters when naming sheets: \ / ? * [ ] and :

Answer (score 0):

MSExcel has following validation for sheet name

[image]

Make sure your sheet name is valid according to above rules